# Div opacity based on scrollbar position

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, opacity, fade

Find an example of how to fade out a `div` when the scroll bar reaches a certain position [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xXxXR/). But it's not a smooth throttle-type fade. Here is the code from that jsfiddle:

```
var divs = $('.social, .title');
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if($(window).scrollTop()<10){
         divs.fadeIn("fast");
   } else {
         divs.fadeOut("fast");
   }
});​
```

I want the opacity percentage to to reflect the position of the scrollbar. For instance when the scroll bar is at very top position, the div opacity is 100%.  When I scroll down 35px I want the opacity of the div to fade down to 0%

Perhaps a technique could be when div A is at 35px from top, div B = 100% opacity.  When div A is 0px from top, div B = 0% opacity.  And have it smoothly fade at all stages in between.

Thanks!

UPDATE:  Thanks for all the help most of them work fairly well, but I really need it to work within the 35px range.  So I have created a new example which will make it very clear how it should work.
http://jsfiddle.net/J8XaX/1/

UPDATE 2: mobile devices:  I tried this on my iPhone and the fade doesn't work smoothly.  The way it works is if you slide halfway and release your finger, then the opacity goes down.  But if you try to scroll smoothly it goes from 100% opacity directly to 0% opacity.  Wondering if there is any way to fix this??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

try something like

```
var divs = $('.social, .title'),
    limit = 35;  /* scrolltop value when opacity should be 0 */

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();

   /* avoid unnecessary call to jQuery function */
   if (st <= limit) {
      divs.css({ 'opacity' : (1 - st/limit) });
   }
});
```

when scrolltop reaches `35px` then opacity of divs is `1 - 35/35 = 0`

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wSkmL/1/
your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/J8XaX/2/ (I've changed 35 to 130px to achieve the effect you wrote in the orange div)

Comment: Tried it and didn't work, but you've got the concept I need.  Scrolling 35px down should make the div fade out.  I've created a new fiddle, perhaps give it a whirl?

Answer (score 7):

```
var divs = $('.social, .title');
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var percent = $(document).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height());
   divs.css('opacity', 1 - percent);
});
```

> `$(document).height() - $(window).height()`: the scrolling area
>   `$(document).scrollTop()`: the current scroll position
>   `percent`: the current scroll position in percent
>   `divs.css('opacity', 1 - percent);`: sets the opacity of the divs

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/xXxXR/7/).

Comment: Thanks, it works very smooth, but I need it to work within a 35px limit.  Please see my new example.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4):

```
var divs = $('.social, .title');
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var fadeval = 1 - ($(window).scrollTop()) / ($(window).height());       
    divs.css({opacity: fadeval});
});​
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ghokun/eMP7w/)

edit: wow so many answer beat me while I was posting

edit: 2

```
    var divs = $('.fademe');
$(document).ready(function(){divs.css('opacity', 0);}); //can be done using CSS also
$(window).scroll(function(){

    var percent = $(document).scrollTop() / (35);
    divs.css('opacity', percent);       
});​
```

[Updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ghokun/5LVhk/)

Comment: Great job, but I need it to work in the 35px limit.  Please check my new example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var divs = $('.social, .title'); 
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var p = $(window).scrollTop()/ $(window).height();
    divs.stop().fadeTo("fast",p);
});
```

Comment: Works too, but need the 35px limit.. please check my new example.  Thanks!