# Javascript fixed scrolling positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

This is my [site](http://aaloktrivedi.com/print_eff.html)

As you can see, I have the sidebar links scroll as I scroll down...but when you go down as far as the footer, the links overlap the footer and don't look good.

I need a way so that the sidebar links are only about 20-30px from the top of the screen after I scroll down (say, about 350px give or take a few) and then return to its original position when I scroll back up.

(if there's a way you can do something like this with just css, that would be ideal, but I'm pretty sure you can't)

Comment: I notice other issues with your `scroll` method you might not be aware about. First, I don't see the text-links overlapping when my browser is *full screen* in vertical size (My monitor is 1920x1200). When I resize the height of my browser so it's 75% tall, then I see the issue you've described. When my browser height is 50% tall (try that yourself), then the scrolling is infinite! To further complicate things, whenever you use browser zoom (Ctrl and +), the scrolling method breaks entirely no matter the height of the browser window.

Comment: can you show the code that you are using

Comment: Yea I am aware of those. Thats why I am trying to fix it so its less problematic. I'm a beginner so I know there's a lot of problems. I don't know any javascript so I'm just relying on what I can find on the Internet. You can view the code by viewing the page source. Its the 2nd script function in the head tags.

Answer (score 0):

run an `if` statement that tests if the user has scrolled all the way to the bottom and if that's the case update the css `top` via jQuery:

```
$('.sidebar').css('top', parseInt($('.sidebar').css('top'), 10) - 'value to shift by' + 'px');
```

`parseInt($('.sidebar').css('top'), 10)` obtains the current top value as an integer that you can then add to, to move the sidebar to a desirable position.

Answer (score 0):

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10203888/1071979)

```
var divs = $('.social, .title');
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   divs.css({ 'opacity' : (1 - st/35) });
});
```

Go to the link above and look at the examples below the code.

when scrolltop reaches 35px then opacity of divs is 1 - 35/35 = 0

[example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wSkmL/1/)

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J8XaX/2/)

Comment: i dont want any opacity to change. I just want the sidebar to stay fixed around 30px from the top after I scroll down past the sidebar's original position. I can even do without the little animated scroll I currently have it doing. Thank you though!

Comment: Try wrapping the sidebar div with another div with a fixed height of 30 px. That way sidebar wont go further than its parent div.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create an additional stop div where you want to stop your scrolling div from further scrolling.i have created a fiddle, maybe it will help you to understand better

**HTML**

```
<div id="fixeddiv">
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
     Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>

    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    <div id="scrollstopdiv"></div>
    Demo 3<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>

    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
    Demo 1<br/>
</div>
<div id="scrollingDiv">scrolling div</div>
```

**JS**

```
$().ready(function() {
        var $scrollingDiv      = $("#scrollingDiv");

         var tksheight         = $("#scrollingDiv").height();
        var tksposition      = $("#scrollstopdiv").position();

        var stopdiv = tksposition.top - (tksheight+400);//adjust position to stop scrolling 

   $(window).scroll(function(){            
   if($(window).scrollTop() > 5 && $(window).scrollTop() < stopdiv){    <!-- -->
                $scrollingDiv
                .stop()
                .animate({"paddingTop": ($(window).scrollTop()+300) + "px"}, "slow" );
            }
        });
    });
```

**CSS**

```
#fixeddiv {width:50px;float:left;padding-right:130px;}
#scrollingDiv{float:left;width:150px;}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CeFXW/2/)