# How to make a div stick to the top and then unstick when page scrolls to a specific scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a website for myself and I am looking for a `div#stickydiv` to stick to the top when the `div#stickydiv` hits the top, but when the `div#finish` reaches the top I want the `div#stickydiv` to then unstick.

Could someone please help me achieve this :)

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Take a look at some plugins that deal with the "viewport". That's the term for area currently being displayed on the monitor.

Comment: Take a look @ http://www.webgeekly.com/tutorials/jquery/a-simple-guide-to-making-a-div-static-as-you-scroll-past-it/

Comment: I answered a similar question recently with the following demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/e9hyw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is certainly more than one way to skin this cat (figuratively speaking, of course ;) ). My recommendation would be to use jQuery + one of the plugins, such as this one:

http://viget.com/inspire/jquery-stick-em

Answer (score -1):

You might check out this question, which is trying to achieve something similar (though they're manipulating opacity and not "stickiness"):

[Div opacity based on scrollbar position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203777/div-opacity-based-on-scrollbar-position)