# jQuery animate opacity 0-1-0

Tags: jquery, opacity, jquery-waypoints

Have found plenty of ways to animate an element when scrolling but they all seem to animate from one state to another, not across three states.

What I want to do is:

- Top of element is entering bottom of viewport: opacity 0
- Element is in middle of viewport: opacity 1
- Bottom of element leaving top of viewport: opacity 0

I want to animate across these three states on the window scroll from opacity 0-1-0

Is is possible?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203777/div-opacity-based-on-scrollbar-position. You should convert the code a bit to let the opacity be 1 at the middle.

Comment: Thanks but that's the kind of post I mentioned I had seen where it animates from 1-0 (or 0-1) but I want to animate opacity in then back out (0-1-0)

Comment: You just have to have two actions per div. Like animate from 0-1 from the top to the middle and from 1-0 from the middle to the bottom (all based on offset probably)

Comment: See my answer, I changed the code of the mentioned answer a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the jsFiddle of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203777/div-opacity-based-on-scrollbar-position) question to get the result, see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J8XaX/294/).

The `opacity` is set based on the scroll position. I've set the `opacity` of the div **before** any scrolling to 0 in CSS. You can change that of course.

Comment: Thanks @Pieter this seems to work. Any idea how it could be repeated down a page? If i had divs (all with the same class) stacked on top of each other and I wanted each of them to fade in then fade out as the came on and left to the screen? The $(document).scrollTop would no longer be valid since it's a calculation between the window and the single div right?

Comment: I guess you should have a look to the `scrollTop()` of a div with `$(selector).scrollTop()`. I don't know whether it works, you should need to experiment a bit ;-)

Comment: But note that the position of your `div` doesn't matter if you want it to work like the jsFiddle. You can position the changing div where you want.

Answer (score 2):

did you mean this:

```
<html>
    <div style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:#666;"></div>
</html>
<script src="../framework/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").animate({"opacity":0});
    $("div").animate({"opacity":1});
    $("div").animate({"opacity":0});
})
</script>
```

Comment: The OP wants it to animate the opacity when it's scrolled to, not on page load