# Element visible only after 300px scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, visible

i only know the basics on coding, and i've hit a dead end right here. Is there a simple code on how to make something visible only when scrolled after a few pixels?

You can see what i mean here http://cocorrinanewtemplate.blogspot.gr
the grey van bar that is fixed, should have a menu visible only when scrolled 300px (that's when the main menu is no longer visible)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203777/div-opacity-based-on-scrollbar-position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" class="back-to-top"></a>
```

**CSS**

```
.back-to-top {display: none; width: 30px; height: 30px; position: fixed; bottom: 20px; right: 20px; z-index: 500;}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function(e) {
            if($(this).scrollTop()>150){
                $('.back-to-top').fadeIn(1000); // Fading in the button on scroll after 150px
            }
            else{
                $('.back-to-top').fadeOut(500); // Fading out the button on scroll if less than 150px
            }
        });

        $('.back-to-top').click(function(e) {
            $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:0}, 800);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You hase to use the **jQuery function** .scroll()

You will have to calculate where are you at in the scrolling proccess, and when you're at 300px from the top, do your logic.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this script might work for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){ 

                $(window).scroll(function(){
                    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                        $('.classid').fadeIn();
                    } else {
                        $('.classid').fadeOut();
                    }
                }); 
     </script>
```

this is your problem on the blinking just remove this script and you will be fine:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>                                                                            

$(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function(e) {
            if($(this).scrollTop()>200){
                $('#menutest').fadeIn(1000); // Fading in the button on scroll after 150px
            }
            else{
                $('#menutest').fadeOut(500); // Fading out the button on scroll if less than 150px
            }
        });


    });

</script>
```

Comment: thanks! i found this one http://jsfiddle.net/psvn9/400/ which is exactly what i'm looking for, but still don't know how to make it work. Blogger is such a pain, have no idea where to put the code. I guess i'll figure it out at some point, thank you for your help!

Comment: an update, made it work, but it starts visible, and keeps blinking all the time :/ any suggestions are very much appreciated! http://cocorrinanewtemplate.blogspot.gr

Comment: can you make a `jsfiddle` with your code for the `menutest`?

Comment: Hi again :) 
Ok, here's the jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/corinanika/ntqpF/ I apologise if it looks like a mess (which i'm sure it is), like i said i'm not a good coder. So even in jsfiddle, it looks odd. Starts with the navbar showing, then not showing then showing again. If you scroll back up and then down, then it works fine. The EXACT same code, still blinks on my layout.. :/ 

If in the end this thing works, besides being so much grateful, i would love to give you proper credit on my blog once it's up (www.cocorrina.com)
once again, thank you for taking the time to help me

Comment: did you delete that script i referenced? I took your code and put it up on a test domain and that worked.... [test](http://www.rrtest13.com)  just look up at my answer I updated it with the script to remove.

Comment: i got confused on which one i should delete and ended up trying both of them. none worked. Weird thing is, i trying your link on my mac (safari) on a windows (chrome & internet explorer) and it doesn't seem to be working. the text on navbar is still there and nothing happens when i scroll down. k, just to makes sure, i want the navbar just the background to be visible when you load the page. And as you scroll, the navbar follows and at some point the text, links and social icons appear. Don't want to be a pain, if it won't work, i'll just change the design

Comment: take a look at the [test site](http://www.rrtest13.com) is this what you are going for?

Comment: I have updated your [jsfiddle](  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/ntqpF/3/). Check it out. Its now working. You had an extra } after #innerdiv style. Also you did not apply any css display:none; property for #menutest. which is why it was being displayed from the beggining.

Comment: oh My GOD! you are absolutely amazing! hah i'm close to tears now :) thank you so so much, yes it worked! now all i have to do is include the social icons as well, but now that's just a piece of cake. Awesome. K, do you have a personal website / twitter that i could credit?