# Attach scroll position to opacity of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, opacity

I have 3 divs, the first is fixed, the second on scroll changes opacity until it's at the same posisiton and then fixes itself. the third waits until the second is positioned then changes it's opacity until it's at the same position and also fixes itself.

The problem is the third div starts always with 50% opacity.

Here is a JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/topaz85/aeemdptb/4/embedded/result/

Here is the script and offending line of code.

```
$("document").ready(function (e) {

var bluetop = $(".pink-bg").outerHeight();
var greentop = $(".pink-bg").outerHeight() + $(".blue-bg").outerHeight();
var footertop = $(".pink-bg").outerHeight() + $(".blue-bg").outerHeight() + $(".green-bg").outerHeight();

var headerHeight = $(".header-container").outerHeight()

$(".blue-bg").css("top", bluetop);
$(".green-bg").css("top", greentop);
$(".approach-section").height(footertop);

$(".pink-bg").css("position", "fixed");

$(".blue-bg, .green-bg").append("<div class='color-bg'></div>");

var bluedistance = $('.blue-bg').offset().top,
    greendistance = $('.green-bg').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();


    if (st + headerHeight >= bluedistance) {
        $(".blue-bg").css({
            "position": "fixed",
            "top": headerHeight
        })
    } else {
        $(".blue-bg").css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "top": bluetop
        })
    }
    if (st + headerHeight >= greendistance) {
        $(".green-bg").css({
            "position": "fixed",
            "top": headerHeight
        })
    } else {
        $(".green-bg").css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "top": greentop
        })
    }

    /* avoid unnecessary call to jQuery function */
    if (st + headerHeight <= bluetop) {
        $(".blue-bg .color-bg").css({
            'opacity': (1 - st / bluetop)
        });
    }

    if (st + headerHeight >= bluetop) {
        var halfScroll = st / 2;
        $(".green-bg .color-bg").css({
            'opacity': (1 - halfScroll / bluetop)
        });
    }

});
```

});

I've looked at this stackoverflow question and have had no luck -[Div opacity based on scrollbar position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203777/div-opacity-based-on-scrollbar-position)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't the second `if` be greentop?

```
if (st + headerHeight <= bluetop) {
    $(".blue-bg .color-bg").css({
        'opacity': (1 - st / bluetop)
    });
}

if (st + headerHeight >= greentop) { <!-- CHANGE HERE -->
    var halfScroll = st / 2;
    $(".green-bg .color-bg").css({
        'opacity': (1 - halfScroll / greentop) <!-- CHANGE HERE -->
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**:

```
if (st+headerHeight <= greentop) {
  var halfScroll = st*2;
  $(".green-bg .color-bg").css({ 'opacity' : (2 - halfScroll/greentop) });
}
```

Played with your settings, all three lines here have some adjustment and it works.

See it working ... **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/aeemdptb/7/)**

Comment: greentop is pinkheight+blueheight at the beginning - so Green's start pos.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/topaz85/aeemdptb/6/embedded/result/ still jumps from grey to green without a transitional fade