# How to have a div change opacity when scrolling? (Parallax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering how to create something like a parallax scrolling effect. The farther you scroll down, the more opaque the div gets, and after a certain point, it starts getting more transparent again. I know JS/JQuery is required to do this. Can someone give me a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: you need scrollTop() and the rest you can figure it out yourself. You should try first before asking for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Div opacity based on scrollbar position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203777/div-opacity-based-on-scrollbar-position)

Answer (score 0):

you should use scrolltop and implement your own logic regarding the math and the div opacity will change as you scroll
this is the function: $(window).scrollTop()

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fiddle for you to help:  Basically you can listen for the scroll event, and control the css opacity property based on the direction.

```
var opc = 1;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
        changeOpacity(0, -0.1)       
   } else {
      changeOpacity(1, +0.1)     
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});

function changeOpacity (limit, amount) {
    if(opc !== limit){
        opc = opc + amount;
        $('#content').css('opacity' , opc);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mvf67/1909/

Hope this helps!